# AWS: Beanstalk: Correct way to Firewall

Tags: clojure, amazon-web-services, firewall, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

### Question

What is the right way to firewall an AWS Beanstalk Instance?

### Context

It is important to for me to firewall because I plan to provide a local Clojure repl/swank instance.

Now, ssh-ed into the beanstalk instance, "sudo iptables --list" looks like:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Now, when I look at the EC2 console (at aws.amazon.com), it shows that at some other level, only ports 22 and 80 are open.

Thus, my question: what is the right layer for me to firewall this off?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The EC2 Security group settings are the right place to configure which ports are open to the world and which not. But keep in mind that HTTP traffic over port 80 must be allowed publically for the application health checks to work properly.

More information on this topic are outlined here:

- [Amazon Web Services: Overview of Security Process document.](http://d36cz9buwru1tt.cloudfront.net/pdf/AWS_Security_Whitepaper.pdf)
- [Amazon EC2 Security Groups for Elastic Beanstalk](http://cloud-computing.learningtree.com/2011/10/31/amazon-ec2-security-groups-for-elastic-beanstalk/)
- [Understanding Amazon EC2 Security Groups and Firewalls](http://cloud-computing.learningtree.com/2010/09/24/understanding-amazon-ec2-security-groups-and-firewalls/)

Comment: These links need to be updated. They don't seem to be valid anymore